# Django runserver not worked after login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I used this command:
`python manage.py runserver 0:8080`

After I logined the system I can reach rest API pages, but can't reach other pages.

Although I send a request, the command output does not log.

```
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the command is:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: Same command :( I tried, not worked.

Comment: You wrote 0:8080 in the post

Comment: Yes. Both commands do the same thing. I tried both though

Answer (score 0):

please check your **urls.py**.
your route to the DRF page, so I think your root URL is just blank,
but check your URL for browsing other routes.

Answer (score 0):

The subject was completely different. I was collecting log somewhere and using it in base.html. But it timed out while printing the page because a lot of logs accumulated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).